# Being a Global Administrator in Azure portal I am unable to configure Continuous Delivery Preview

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, continuous-delivery

Logged into Azure portal--> App Services-->Selected the Project-->Continuous Delivery Preview
I see error message "You do not have enough permissions on this App Service to setup Continuous Delivery. Learn More: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=843472" and Configure button is disabled. I am the Global Administrator and why I don't had the permissions to configure, where I can assign those access.
Error message

> Failed to set Azure permission 'RoleAssignmentId: 9****a' for the
>   service principal '2****3' on subscription id '****': error code:
>   Forbidden, innner error code: AuthorizationFailed, inner error message
>   The client 'my mail Id' with object id '***** does not have
>   authorization to perform action
>   'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope
>   '/subscriptions/*****'. For troubleshooting refer to link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Global Administrator is your directory role. If you want to manage your resource in your subscription, you should give your user `owner`  role.

You could do it on Azure Portal. `<your subscription>--><Access Control>--><Add>`.

[image]

More information about this please refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role).

Note: Find your user(or service principal), if your user does not have owner, please grant it.

Comment: This worked but user should be Owner, contributor role is not having sufficient permissions to configure Delivery Preview.

Comment: @Jagadesh Thanks for you reply, I will update my answer.

Comment: I cannot see owner role in Active directory.Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue as well, please try the following:

1. Turn off all checkboxes in Azure DevOps project settings (Azure DevOps -> Project Settings -> Settings), like this "Limit job authorization scope to the current project for non-release pipelines"
   [DevOps pipeline settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAzph.png)
2. Elevate your permissions to be able to assign Owner to your user using [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin).
3. Assign Owner role to you user: Azure Portal -> Azure subscriptions -> select subscription -> Access control (IAM) tab -> Roles assignments -> Select role Owner, select your user -> Save.